# Problema ao ler palavras do banco de dados com acento ou cedilha

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

Estou a ler a minha tabela categorias do banco de dados  e quando tenho palavras com cedilha ou acentos, aparecem no meu projecto com caracteres estranhos.

Por exemplo, nas categorias tenho um titulo *Avaliações*, no meu projecto este título aparece como: `AVALIA��ES`.

Estive a pesquisar acerca deste problema e percebi que tinha de ter no meu banco de dados o Agrupamento (*Collation*) como *utf8_general_ci*, e também que no topo da minha página deveria conter esta meta: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Contudo, mesmo com estes 2 métodos para solucionar o problema, continuo a ter o meu título como `AVALIA��ES`.

Alguem sabe o que pode estar a acontecer e como poderei resolver isto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu proponho que você faça o seguinte:

1 - Insira estas linhas de código no seu arquivo de conexão ao banco:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

2 - Tenha certeza que o banco de dados esteja em formato UTF-8. Para isso acesse seu banco de dados e vá em Operações (phpmyadmin) e certifique-se de que seu banco está guardando as informações com a codificação certa.

Posta depois se resolver.

Comment: Obrigado marcosvinicius. A solução era mesmo essa, mas no meu caso que estou a utilizar pdo, tem de ser assim: array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")

Comment: Ok fiz o procedimento acima e deu certo. parabéns!

Comment: Camarada, muitoobrigado. Estava com este problema aqui e você me ajudou muito.